# Check: Find all the non-isomorphic Abelian groups of order $200$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Find all the non-isomorphic Abelian groups of order $200$.

Since $200=5^2 \cdot 2^3$, there are $3 \times 2=6$ such groups. The six partitions are:

1. $25 \times 8$
2. $25 \times (4 \times 2)$
3. $25 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2)$
4. $(5 \times 5) \times 8$
5. $(5 \times 5) \times (4 \times 2)$
6. $(5 \times 5) \times (2 \times 2 \times 2)$

So the six Abelian groups of order $200$ are:

1. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_8$
2. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
3. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2$
4. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$
5. $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2$
6. $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely correct. :)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143607/an-abelian-group-of-order-100.