# If G is an abelian group with subgroups H,K of orders 3 and 5, prove there must exist an element of order 15.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

My girlfriend suggested I use Lagrange theorem, but that only deals with finite groups.

If G was finite, and H has order 3 and K has order 5 , then clearly since the orders of H and K must divide the order of G, then there must also be an element of order 15.

But what about if G is infinite?

Edit: if G is infinite, then elements can't have finite order ( except for the identity). Nvm lol

Edit:2 I thought about it for a couple of more minutes and if G can only be finite, then G has order of at least 3, or 5, or any multipleof 3 and 5... the Lcm of 3 and 5 is 15, and so there must be an element of order 15.

Comment: The edit is wrong, infinite groups can have elements of finite order.

Comment: @Mathematician42 care to give an example?

Comment: Take any group and consider the direct sum with some finite group, then the direct sum will have elements of finite order.

Comment: @user338365 Consider the Lie group $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ of non-singular linear transformation of the plane. It contains the reflection in the $x$-axis, which has order two. $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ has elements of all orders, finite and infinite.

Comment: $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ under multiplication is a group with a non-identity element of finite order; the set of (complex) roots of unity is an infinite group in which *every* element has finite order.

Comment: @pjs36 But your second examplt isn't finitely generated (not even countably generated), so it shouldn't really count.  For example the countable product $\prod \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite and every element has finite order.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ has subgroups $H_1=\langle h_1\rangle$ and $H_2=\langle h_2\rangle$ of orders $3$ and $5$ respectively, what can you say about the group $\langle h_1,h_2\rangle$?

Also, a note that your edit is not true.  There are infinite finitely generated groups in which every element has finite order.  The Grigorchuk group is an example.

Comment: Do you mind explaining to me what <h1,h2> represents? Sorry it's been two years since I took algebra. My intuition is the set generated by the product of elements in <h1> and elements of <h2>

Comment: @user338365 This is the group generated by the two elements $h_1$ and $h_2$.  You could alternatively think about the group generated by the product $h_1\cdot h_2$.  For example, what is the order of this element?

Comment: clearly, the order cannot be 3 or 5, but a multiple of those two ------> must have order 15.

Comment: @user338365 That's exactly the point.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143607/an-abelian-group-of-order-100?rq=1 for a similar question with way more details.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ has a subgroup $H_1$ of order $3$ which is cyclic .Hence $H_1$ has an element of order $3$ say $a$ and so does $G$.

Similarly $G$ has an element of order $5$ say $b$.

Now $\gcd(o(a),o(b))=1$ and $ab=ba\implies o(ab)=o(a)o(b)=3\times 5=15$